# PHP Optgroup in Foreach

Tags: php, foreach, payment, optgroup

i'm on making payment system dropdown system, and have issue, with optgroup for mobile payments. This is example, of response from MySQL.

```
[17]=>
array(5) {
["id"]=>
string(2) "34"
["region"]=>
string(1) "1"
["type"]=>
string(2) "18"
["mobile"]=>
string(1) "0"
["system"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
[18]=>
 array(5) {
["id"]=>
string(2) "35"
["region"]=>
string(1) "1"
["type"]=>
string(2) "19"
["mobile"]=>
string(1) "0"
["system"]=>
string(1) "1"
 }
[19]=>
array(5) {
["id"]=>
string(2) "36"
["region"]=>
string(1) "1"
["type"]=>
string(2) "20"
["mobile"]=>
string(1) "1"
["system"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
[20]=>
array(5) {
["id"]=>
string(2) "37"
["region"]=>
string(1) "1"
["type"]=>
string(2) "20"
["mobile"]=>
string(1) "2"
["system"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
[21]=>
array(5) {
["id"]=>
string(2) "38"
["region"]=>
string(1) "1"
["type"]=>
string(2) "20"
["mobile"]=>
string(1) "3"
["system"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
```

So where ['type'] === 20 && ['mobile'] != 0 i need for making optgroup with label mobile payments..

```
if ( ! empty ( $regions ) && $regions !== NULL ) {

    $array = array();

    $im = 0;
    $i = 0;

    var_dump( $regions );

    foreach ( $regions as $key => $region ) {

        if ( (int) $region['mobile'] === 0 ) {
            $type  = $db->getTypeById( (int) $region['type'] );
            $value = $region['type'];

            echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$type}</option>";

        } else {

            //if ( $i < 1 )
            //echo '<optgroup label="Mobile payments">';

            $type  = $db->getMobileById( (int) $region['mobile'] );
            $value = $region['type'] . '_' . $region['mobile'];

            echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$type}</option>";

            //if ( $i <= $im )
            //echo '</optgroup>';

            $i++;

        }

    }

}
```

[My dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75cA.gif)

So my problem is to make proper group without repeating it on every mobile payments in each region (continent)

Should be soemthing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/atc67mLe/24/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the optgroup in the middle of your options, you could just add it at the end.

```
if (!empty($regions)) {

    $mobileOptions = [];

    // Print normal options
    foreach ($regions as $region) {

        $typeId = $region['type'];

        if ($typeId == 20 && $region['mobile'] != 0) {
            $mobileOptions[] = $region;
        } else {
            $label = $db->getTypeById($typeId);
            echo "<option value='{$typeId}'>{$label}</option>";
        }
    }

    // Print mobile options
    if (!empty($mobileOptions)) {
        echo '<optgroup label="Mobile payments">';

        foreach ($mobileOptions as $region) {

            $mobileId = $region['mobile'];
            $typeId = $region['type'];
            $label  = $db->getMobileById($mobileId);

            echo "<option value=\"{$typeId}_{$mobileId}\">{$label}</option>";
        }
        echo '</optgroup>';
    }
}
```

This is untested, but you get the idea. Just separate the mobile ones into a new array and loop through them to make the optgroup afterwards.

I would probably try to refine the initial SQL query though, to retrieve a more usable set of results rather than running a bunch of extra queries in the loop for every option. It would be better to have a join in your first SQL query, to get the payment method name at the same time.

Comment: Hi, big thank you, yeah how, i didn't think about one more foreach :)) Its works perfectly! You have stronger logic thinking ;) Good andswer, and explained!

Answer (score 0):

the issue in your code is you wrapping each mobile payment option with optgroup. What you have to do is to group all mobile payment options in array or in a string and then wrapping them all with optgroup before print them out

here is an example ...

```
$options = '';
$mobileOptions = '';

foreach ($regions as $region) {

    $typeId = $region['type'];

    if ($typeId == 20 && $region['mobile'] != 0) {

        $label  = $db->getMobileById($region['mobile']);
        $mobileOptions .= sprintf('<option value="%s_%s">%s</option>',$typeId,$region['mobile'],$label);

    } else {

        $label = $db->getTypeById($typeId);
        $options .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',$typeId,$label);

    }

}

echo $options;
if ($mobileOptions)
    echo '<optgroup label="Mobile payments">'.$mobileOptions.'</optgroup>';
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This doesn't works, and make all mobile payments with Mobile payment! :/
Thank you.